Reverse Y axis of SwiftUI Chart
Currently with the below default configuration from SwiftUI Charts, it is plotting top to bottom, i.e. minimum to maximum top to bottom. See the attached picture. I want the axis flipped so its plotting bottom to top.
struct HeartRateChart: View {
    let dateInterval: DateInterval
    let segments: [HeartRateSegment]
    let maxHeartRate: CGFloat
    let minHeartRate: CGFloat
    
    init(dateInterval: DateInterval, segments: [HeartRateSegment], maxHeartRate: Int, minHeartRate: Int) {
        self.dateInterval = dateInterval
        self.segments = segments
        self.maxHeartRate = CGFloat(maxHeartRate)
        self.minHeartRate = CGFloat(minHeartRate)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(segments, id: \.startDate) { segment in
                let yStart: CGFloat = CGFloat(segment.samples.min()?.heartRate ?? 0)
                let yEnd: CGFloat = CGFloat(segment.samples.max()?.heartRate ?? 0)
                RuleMark(x: .value("startDate", segment.startDate), yStart: yStart, yEnd: yEnd)
            }
        }
        .chartYScale(domain: [minHeartRate, maxHeartRate], range: minHeartRate...maxHeartRate)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: [minHeartRate, maxHeartRate])
        }
        .chartXScale(domain: [dateInterval.start, dateInterval.end])
        .chartPlotStyle { content in
            content.frame(height: 200)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}



So just do domain: [maxHeartRate, minHeartRate] instead of domain: [minHeartRate, maxHeartRate]? Did I understand correctly?

Yes, you're understanding correctly. I tested your suggestion but didn't get the desired result. The graph still lays as the provided screenshot.

If I understand the problem correctly, the values and labels are not plotting with the minimum(on bottom) to maximum(on top). Try changing the values to plottable values. This should fix the values, labels and the domain range.
Use PlottableValue's .value for yStart and yEnd in the RuleMark, like this:
RuleMark(
    x: .value("startDate", segment.startDate),
    yStart: .value("min", yStart), 
    yEnd: .value("max", yEnd))

The result:

These are the heart rate ranges for the first 5 marks of the chart shown:

I'm pasting my complete test based on your example because I made some minor changes for syntax reasons and made some assumptions about how the HeartRateSegment was structured.
Hopefully this offers some help if you haven't resolved it already.
    import SwiftUI
    import Charts
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            HeartRateChart(dateInterval: DateInterval(start: .now, end: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 60, to: .now) ?? .now), segments: heartRateSegments, maxHeartRate: 132, minHeartRate: 77)
        }
    }
    
    struct HeartRateChart: View {
        let dateInterval: DateInterval
        let segments: [HeartRateSegment]
        let maxHeartRate: Int
        let minHeartRate: Int
        
        init(dateInterval: DateInterval, segments: [HeartRateSegment], maxHeartRate: Int, minHeartRate: Int) {
            self.dateInterval = dateInterval
            self.segments = segments
            self.maxHeartRate = maxHeartRate
            self.minHeartRate = minHeartRate
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            Chart {
                ForEach(segments, id: \.startDate) { segment in
                    let yStart = segment.heartRate.min() ?? 0
                    let yEnd = segment.heartRate.max() ?? 0
                    RuleMark(x: .value("startDate", segment.startDate),
                            yStart: .value("min", yStart),
                                yEnd: .value("max", yEnd))
                }
            }
            .chartYScale(domain: [minHeartRate, maxHeartRate])
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: [minHeartRate, maxHeartRate])
            }
            .chartXScale(domain: [dateInterval.start, dateInterval.end])
            .chartPlotStyle { content in
                content.frame(height: 100)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    struct HeartRateSegment: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        let startDate: Date
        let heartRate: [Int]
    }
    
    // Randomly creates some heartrate data. Each segment represents a minute.
    let heartRateSegments: [HeartRateSegment] = {
        var segments: [HeartRateSegment] = []
        
        for j in stride(from: 0, to: 3600, by: 60) { // every minute for 1 hour (in seconds)
            let minheartRate = Int.random(in: 77...107)
            let span = Int.random(in: 5...25)
            let heartRates = [minheartRate, minheartRate + span]
            print(heartRates)
            segments.append( HeartRateSegment(startDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(j)), heartRate: heartRates))
        }
        
        return segments
    }()

